# $_POST запрос, суперглобальная перменная

Tags: php, yii

Есть форма, которая отправляет данные , в экшен:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand();



    $command->insert('order', array(
        'email' => $_POST['mail'],
        'cid' => $_POST['cid'],
        'phone' => $_POST['phoneOrder'],
        'source' => 'еуые',
        'date' => $date,
    ));
```

После отправки формы - смотрю в базу, заполненые поля mail  на месте ( которые передаются в  $_POST['mail'])

Делаю var_dump($_POST) перед этим всем, пробую отправить, и суперглобальная переменная пуста!

В форме метод post, та и вообще как бы все в базу попадает. В чем проблема?

Comment: Вот эту часть как то не могу понять `Делаю var_dump($_POST) перед этим всем, пробую отправить, и суперглобальная переменная пуста!`,
Можно иными словами обяснить?

Comment: я проверяю что приходит из формы. делаю в экшене  var_dump($_POST);die;  и отправляю форму, и смотрю что пришло.

Comment: И где оно уже пусто?

Comment: вообще в yii для этого есть Yii::app()->post, к примеру...... более того...... для запросов имеются модели, которые получают данные из запросов например `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), 'MyModel')`

Comment: нет такого свойста и метода у yii1 Yii::app()->post

Comment: Возможно вы за yii2?